# Spinner в android

Tags: android, android-spinner

как сделать свой стиль (картинки , текст, отступ) для каждого пункта в spinner ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать свой адаптер, который принимает список соответствующих объектов. И `layout` в котором Вы разместите соответствующие контролы с картинками, стилями и т.д.

В `Activity` создаёте этот адаптер. Передаёте в него список объектов для вывода и Ваш `layout`. После назначаете адптер спиннеру.

Пример кода можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.zoftino.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter-&-layout).